# Publish vb.net mvc web application to local folder error "One or more errors occurred"

Tags: git, deployment, visual-studio-2019

After I merged my project using git and fixed all conflicts , I can't publish it successfully.

My project builds successfully, but it is failed when I try to publish it to local folder .
It pops up a windows shows **"One or more errors occurred"**,but there don't any detail about the error appear on output windows.

I try to fixed it by
1.update my Visual Studio version to (Community 2019 version 16.8.3)
2.change the folder where I publish
3.delete all contents inside origin folder then publish again

but it's still same.

How can I do next to fixed the error or find more clue about it? Thanks.